# Running a script when a sound from an application is played

Tags: windows, audio, triggers

I would like to trigger a script on my computer (Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bit) when a particular event occurs (event 'X'). There is already an application on my computer which plays a 1 second chime (.wav sound file) whenever event X occurs. Therefore, I would like to trigger my script whenever this sound file is being played.

How can I trigger a script to run when a particular sound file is played?

Comment: You'll have better luck telling us what that event is and to ask for ways to hook this event directly.  In other words, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: The event is application specific and cannot be hooked directly. What I'm really trying to do is run a script whenever a particular sound file is being played by that application.

Comment: Essentially, I have an application which chimes whenever something particular is sent on a network. I don't want to be too specific because it requires knowledge of a system which is not really relevant to what I want to do. I've looked at ways of hooking the event directly, and it would be best to have a solution which triggers from the sound file.